# Advice for Android code structure. Background process

Tags: android, android-service, android-bluetooth

I come from the world of .NET / Microsoft... very new to the Android framework.

My goal is to implement an Android app that has some interface features, but also runs in the background processing Bluetooth RFCOMM data inputs. When the phone is locked, screen shuts down, the process needs to run happily in the background.

I have had some success with connecting to the Bluetooth device but am a bit confused with how to setup the framework in general. At this point in time I'm locking up the UI and need to structure my code properly in a background thread of some sort.

1. Should I be using an "IntentService" to achieve the long running background process that will run continually, even if the phone is locked.
2. If I use an "IntentService", can I have global variables that are referenced by various Action requests to the service... so, if I call 'Action A' in the Intent service and modify a private class level variable in the Intent Service, will that variable be available to a later call 'Action B' to the service?  Basically I'm hoping to have a service class which has things like a private variable for the Bluetooth socket connection... first 'Action' call to the service will connect, if OK then a later call to another 'Action' in the same service will perform other work, using the private variable that was setup in the first 'Action' call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you understand what you need to do for what you want. That is if your service really needs to be running when the device is asleep. I wrote a service that took this approach, if you'd like an example:

https://github.com/zuberfowler/PillMinder/blob/master/src/edu/elon/cs/pillminder/PillMinderService.java

Comment: Thanks for the link :-) I've got a working flow going now using an Intent Service, seems to be hanging together okay so far.

It's a bit fiddly working with Bluetooth because I haven't been able to setup a working development environment which emulates it, so I have to compile and deploy to my phone for each test! But, I did take a step back and build a project to play around with the service and messaging processes without having to worry about the Bluetooth side which made life a bit easier.